# Lost Partition on x3650

Tags: hardware-raid, ibm-xseries, partition-table

I have a RAID6 array with 1 logical drive. 3.7TB. The partition has been lost. I've tried several program to recover the partition. The most promising of the bunch was MiniTool Partition Wizard. It found the partition, and you could preview the file structure correctly, but when I tried to have it repair it just went back to an unallocated status.

Server Info: IBM Series x3650 7945. MegaRAID M5015

TestDisk gives the following error: partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xaa55

If anyone has any suggestions about getting the partition online or recover the data I'm all ears... I will provide more information if needed... Going on 24 hours straight at this so I may be lacking in providing some information.

Comment: Once upon a time I used a program named GetDataBack, it does a sector by sector scan. Not free though.

Comment: Are you sure the hardware is O.K.?

Comment: Hardware is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition recovery didn't work, having to do data recovery... No partition repairs would work.. if anyone is interested in a good data recovery utility. GetDataBack is a great utility that will scan the MFT entries and build a file list based on the MFT.